# Adobe Creative Cloud: Mac App Alternatives

Tags: discussion, blog

I recently asked a question [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/90768/adobe-creative-cloud-mac-app-alternatives) regarding Adobe Creative Cloud: Mac App Alternatives which according to @bmike has been temporarily closed. In hindsight should have asked here first, but sometimes I get too excited.

Its probably a good idea for an Ask Different Blog Post instead. Can we work out an outline or at least gauge interest in a blog post here?

Answer (score 1):

See here [What's wrong with a question asking for alternatives to Adobe CS in the cloud?](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1676/whats-wrong-with-a-question-asking-for-alternatives-to-adobe-cs-in-the-cloud)

Again, I want to thank you so much for asking it and being excited about the site and about generating good relevant content.

We can use this question to work on some blog post outlines and the other question to hash out what to do with the original question.

Comment: Ok thanks very much

Comment: This comment should go here rather than on the other question: Obviously good alternatives exist IMHO eg Pixelmator in place of Photoshop, iDraw instead of illustrator, Camtasia instead of Premiere etc etc. If there is a way to collate them

Comment: @simon Yes - we have tags on the main site, so for starters look at the questions that are tagged both [tag:adobe] and [tag:software-recommendation]

Comment: Yes that right, in terms of CS in the cloud this is the first one

Comment: Still no reponses to the other question...strange

Comment: I'd give it time - if after 3 or 4 days, no one wants to discuss it (or better, makes an edit to the question to kick it to the re-open queue) them perhaps we'll know if people don't have an opinion and/or are OK with it being closed.

Comment: Ok fine, lets wait.

Comment: You certainly don't have to wait - you can answer that other question to get the ball rolling on explaining why it should be reopened unless you now agree that it's not a good fit...

Comment: Ok fine, i'll do it tomorrow. I find it strange that no one makes a comment, even if its a negative one. I guess they must have the money to spend.